# Malwarebytes Task Tray Icon sometimes does not Load

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, icons, malwarebytes

Just recently, I noticed that the task tray icon for Malwarebytes does not always load when I start up Windows 8.1. Sometimes it does, and sometimes it does not. Whenever it does not, I still open Task Manager and find it running in the background. I want the Task Tray icon to load every time. What is the cause of this, and what can I do about it to stop this from occurring?

Comment: Do you have it set to 'show icon and notifications' in the 'Notifications area icons' in control panel?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I have it set to "only show notifications" which is how I had it set before and how I want it to be set. The problem is that sometimes clicking the arrow to see the rest of the icons does not always have the Malwarebytes icon shown as it should.

Comment: What version of Malwarebytes are you running, and when did this problem start occurring?  Lots of people are saying the latest version 2.0 is very buggy.

Comment: @pacoverflow I am running version 2.0.2.1012. I only started noticing this either on Thursday or Friday.

Comment: @DavidB Was there an auto update to Malwarebytes on Thursday or Friday?

Comment: You would be better off posting on the malwarebytes forum - especially if you have a subscription - Their support is excellent.

Comment: @pacoverflow The version number that I gave you came out last week, so yes.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I have posted this on their website as well, but the issue seems to have disappeared.

Comment: use ccleaner,in it,there is an advanced section in windows tab,tick the tray notification cache and then run cleaner :)
(experimental-just guessing)

Comment: This seems to be a problem with MBAM. I do not know why it happens though.